# Why can we assign a value to a function that has not been defined yet?

Tags: core-language, language-design

Consider the following snippet,

```
fib[1] = fib[2] = 1;
fib[n_Integer] := fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2]
```

As a newbie, it seems for me, the first line assigns 1 to  `fib[1]` and `fib[2]` whereas the `fib` has not been defined yet.

#### Question

How can we do that? What is the philosophy behind it (from Mathematica Language's  point of view)?

Comment: This question might be too simple, but confusing for me!

Comment: Mathematica is a system of symbols that does not need to be "defined" (whatever you mean by "defining a symbol"). If a symbol x is new, there is nothing to do with it, so it simply stays inert, that is to say If you ask to evaluate x the answer is x.

Comment: See http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node17.html for a discussion of rewrite rules, downvalues, and what functions really are in *Mathematica*.

Comment: The complete definition of the recursion is `fib[1] = fib[2] = 1;
fib[n_Integer?Positive] := fib[n] = fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2];
fib[n_Integer?NonPositive] := fib[n] = fib[n + 2] - fib[n + 1];` Check with `And @@ (Fibonacci[#] == fib[#] & /@ Range[-25, 25])`

Comment: Even in just mathematics, `fib[1] = fib[2] = 1` is a definition of the function `fib`. It just defines the specific values of the function at the specific point, 1 and 2, although it doesn't cover all domain of the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to have expectations that do not conform to the structure of *Mathematica* definitions and assignments.  As Alan notes in his answer `f[1] = value` is *already* a definition, specifically a [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) rule attached to the Symbol `f`.  Such definitions are common in *Mathematica*, and at least in some contexts are known as *indexed objects*:

- [Tutorial: Making Definitions for Indexed Objects](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html)

Many definitions attached to the same Symbol can coexist in *Mathematica*, and their order of application is determined by certain rules including pattern specificity.  Consider for example:

```
f[a_] = 3;
f[1] = 5;

f[1]
```

> ```
> 5
> ```

This happens because `1` is considered *more specific* than `_`, and this definition is placed higher in the rules list despite being specificed second.

```
?f
```

> Global`f
>
> ```
> f[1]=5
>
> f[a_]=3
> ```

Answer (score 5):

In fact, you did already define the "function", but only for certain values.

```
ClearAll[fib]
DownValues[fib]  (* no down values *)
fib[1]  (* no downvalues, so no substitution *)
(* add down values: *)
fib[1] = fib[2] = 1;  (* add down values *)
DownValues[fib]  (* two down values *)
fib[1]  (* matches a down value, so substitution *)
fib[3]  (* does not match, so no substitution *)
fib[n_Integer] := 
 fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2]  (* add another down value *)
DownValues[fib]  (* three down values *)
fib[3] (* now this matches, so substitution *)
```